# Validation in Symfony2 form not working

Tags: symfony

i've created a form and when I send it to the server then I get an internal server error because there are empty fields which are not allowed. But i'm wondering because I check the form with the following code, so that normally the database actions should be skipped. What could be the reason?

Controller:

```
public function newAction(Request $request) {

    $objTrip = new Trip();
    $objForm = $this->createForm(new TripType, $objTrip);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $objForm->bind($request);

        if ($objForm->isValid()) {
            $objEm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $objEm->persist($objTrip);
            $objEm->flush();

            $response = new Response(json_encode(array('success' => true)));
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return $response;
        }

        // Es traten Fehler auf
        $arrErrors = array();
        foreach($objForm as $objField) {

            if($objField->hasErrors())
                foreach($objField->getErrors() as $objError)
                    $arrErrors[] = array($objField->var['id'] => $objError->getMessage());
        }
        $response = new Response(json_encode(array('success' => false, 'errors' => $arrErrors)));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }

    return array('form' => $objForm->createView());
}
```

Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 * @Assert\MinLength(
 *     limit=3
 * )
 */
protected $startLocation;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $endLocation;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $startTime;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
 */
protected $price;
```

Comment: Show the validators you have defined for your entity

Comment: /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
 
 /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
  * @Assert\MinLength(
     *     limit=3
     * )
     */
 protected $startLocation;
 
 /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
 protected $endLocation;
 
 /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
 protected $startTime;
 
 /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
 protected $price;

Comment: Could you also provide the FormType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gerrit, Hi, looks like you didn't use NotBlank constraint. MinLength skip empty values.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 * @Assert\MinLength(
 *     limit=3
 * )
 */
protected $startLocation;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $endLocation;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $startTime;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
 */
protected $price;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned normally appears when you got fields in formtype which are not present in the Entity.

Can you therefore show us the FormType aswell?

Answer (score 0):

@Flask, not only - for me normally internal exception appears when i wont set proper (for example) NotBlank validator for notnull field and turn off html5 validation or make functional tests), but ofc will be great to look at FormType :)

Btw. (sorry for offtop) is it normal that i can comment only my own answer?